# Error in uploading audio from client to server using p5

Tags: node.js, audio, server, client, p5.js

We are a group of five students from Politecnico di Milano in italy!
We are following a creative coding course and in order to present our final project, we need to solve some little problems: we have to find a way to upload audio files from client and save them in the server.

Our problem (as you can see from the image below) is that the function getBlob() does not work, could you please give us a little help to run the code properly?

[image: error]

We link the repository that we are using: https://github.com/ikilol/Soundloading
Thank you so much! :)

Here is the relevant client side source code:

```
let button;
let mic;
let soundRec;
let soundFile;


function setup() {
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
  soundRec = new p5.SoundRecorder();
  soundRec.setInput(mic)
  soundFile = new p5.SoundFile();

  button = createDiv("");
  button.position(100,100);
  button.size(100,100);
  button.style('background-color', 'grey');


  button.mouseClicked((mouseEvent)=>{
    console.log("recording....");
    soundRec.record(soundFile); // set up the soundfile to record and start recording

    let recordingTimer = setTimeout(()=>{ // setup a timeout for the recording, after the time below expires, do the tings inside the {}

      soundRec.stop(); // stop recording

      let soundBlob = soundFile.getBlob(); //get the recorded soundFile's blob & store it in a variable


      let formdata = new FormData() ; //create a from to of data to upload to the server
      formdata.append('soundBlob', soundBlob,  'myfiletosave.wav') ; // append the sound blob and the name of the file. third argument will show up on the server as req.file.originalname

          // Now we can send the blob to a server...
      var serverUrl = '/upload'; //we've made a POST endpoint on the server at /upload
      //build a HTTP POST request
      var httpRequestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formdata , // with our form data packaged above
        headers: new Headers({
          'enctype': 'multipart/form-data' // the enctype is important to work with multer on the server
        })
      };
      // console.log(httpRequestOptions);
      // use p5 to make the POST request at our URL and with our options
      httpDo(
        serverUrl,
        httpRequestOptions,
        (successStatusCode)=>{ //if we were successful...
          console.log("uploaded recording successfully: " + successStatusCode)
        },
        (error)=>{console.error(error);}
      )
      console.log('recording stopped');

    },1000) //record for one second

  }) // close mouseClicked handler


} //close setup()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this happens when the mic is not actually initialized when you start recording. The microphone will need to be initialized in response to user input (i.e. a mouse click), and this will need to happen before you start recording.